# Adicionar componentes ao instalar o Unity

Tags: unity3d

Procurei em inúmeras páginas antigas bem como na internet e não achei uma solução.

Quando atualizava o Unity 2018.2, apareceu na tela alguns componentes básicos para instalar. Acabei acrescentando o Facebook Gameroon.

Se eu quiser adicionar outros componentes, exemplos do VR, Android etc, como é feito isto? Terei que desinstalar e instalar tudo novamente?

Comment: Já tentou executar o instalador da Unity de novo, escolhendo os pacotes que deseja? Tirei esse processo [deste link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1122671/download-unity-components-that-we-have-missed-duri.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Isso solucionou o seu problema?

Comment: Desculpa. Não tive tempo ainda de tentar a solução. Ter que instalar tudo novamente. Dias escuros por aqui no momento. Vou ver depois e verifico isto. Agradecido pela ajuda.